# Swift: strange effect when magnifier approaches too much to the borders of view to magnify

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

As you can see from the following screenshot

[image]

if I approach too much to the border of the view to magnify (which is a `UIView` containing the `UIImageView`) then I get that annoying and strange effect. So I have tried to set the whole `UIViewController.view` as the view to magnify and 
in effect that effect disappears but look what happens instead:

[image]

It seems that the magnified zone showed in the magnifier circle does not correspond anymore to the one where I am tapping (with the cursor of the mouse). I would like the magnifier to be fixed in a zone of the screen that I will calculate according to the position where the user taps; for the moment I put it at the center. This is my class of the magnifier

```
import UIKit

public class MagnifyingGlassView: UIView {

var viewToMagnify: UIView?
var scale: CGFloat = 2.0
var zoomedPoint:CGPoint?

var size: CGFloat = 200.0 {
    didSet {
        let c = center
        frame = CGRectMake(c.x - size / 2, c.y - size / 2, size, size)
    }
}
var outlineColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        layer.borderColor = outlineColor?.CGColor
    }
}
var outlineWidth: CGFloat? {
    didSet {
        layer.borderWidth = outlineWidth ?? 0.0
    }
}

var touchPoint: CGPoint = CGPointZero {
    didSet {
        self.center = touchPoint
    }
}

required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    commonInit()
}

required public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

public init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size))
    commonInit()
}

public override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        else { return }
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, frame.size.width / 2, frame.size.height / 2)
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scale, scale)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -zoomedPoint!.x, -zoomedPoint!.y)

    hidden = true
    viewToMagnify?.layer.renderInContext(context)

    /* color of axes */
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    /* line width of axes */
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5)

    /* draw vertical axis inside magnifier */
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.zoomedPoint!.x , self.zoomedPoint!.y - (self.frame.size.height / 2))
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.zoomedPoint!.x, self.zoomedPoint!.y + (self.frame.size.height / 2))

    /* draw horizontal axis inside magnifier */
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.zoomedPoint!.x - (self.frame.size.width / 2), self.zoomedPoint!.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.zoomedPoint!.x + (self.frame.size.width / 2), self.zoomedPoint!.y)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    hidden = false

}

private func commonInit() {
    layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width / 2
    layer.masksToBounds = true
}
}
```

where `zoomedPoint` is the point in the screen where the user is tapping. Do you know how to correct this?